# Userform on a specific WB

Tags: excel, vba, reference, userform

I have a userform on a specific WorkBook and what it does is it collects data from a user and dumps it on that same WorkBook . My problem is, if I have that WB minimized and another WB open and I fill up the userform, the data wont dump on the minimized workbook. I'm not sure how to reference that specific WorkBook so that even if other WorkBook are open it will still dump my data on my intended WorkBook . Is that all possible? if so, how?

here is my code for reference.

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
ActiveWorkbook.AcceptAllChanges
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If

    If txtCallID.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a Call ID.", vbExclamation, "CALL ID FIELD ERROR"


'if all fields were answered, show Message Box for confirmation
    Else
        Dim response As Integer


        response = MsgBox("Please review all information before proceeding." & vbCrLf & "Click YES to Proceed, Click NO to review.", _
                vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Audit Tracker")

     End If
        If response = vbYes Then

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    Set ws = Worksheets("Data Sheet")
    'find  first empty row in database
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("E2", ws.Cells(lRow - 1, 1)), Me.txtCallID.Value) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Somebody is already auditing this call", vbCritical, "Duplicate Call ID"
        Me.txtCallID.Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If



     'check for a segement id
    If Trim(Me.txtCallID.Value) = "" Then
        Me.txtCallID.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter the Call ID"
        Exit Sub
    End If

     'copy the data to the database
     With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = txtDate.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Environ$("username")
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.txtCallID.Value


If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
ActiveWorkbook.AcceptAllChanges
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If

     'clear the data
    Me.txtCallID.Value = ""

    Me.txtCallID.SetFocus
   End With
   End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

What I'm hoping to do is to always dump the data to my workbook which is DataTracker.xlsd

Comment: If with dumping you mean something like pasting in the selection than I can understand why this will not work. If you define your target well (as a range object for instance) this has a better chance of working. A bit hard to know what you are after... try including some code.

Comment: I've edited my post. I hope you can now understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

> so that even if other WorkBook are open it will still dump my data on my intended WorkBook

`ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook owning the form or the code module being executed. On the other hand, ActiveWorkbook refers to the currently active workbook in Excel, whichever one it is. To fix your code:

Replace `ActiveWorkbook` by `ThisWorkbook`.

Also: `Set ws = Worksheets("Data Sheet")`

by `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Sheet")`

because without specifying `ThisWorkbook`, the `Worksheets` function having no qualifier, will fetch in the worksheets of the ActiveWorkbook (default behavior), and will probably fail.

Comment: It actually worked!! thanks, by the way do you mind helping me with improving my vba as well. Since everytime a user submits his data it autosaves the workbook. it takes a long time for the userform to finish loading. Any suggestion in making my code run a bit faster?

Comment: @user5500328 I looked into the code. Unfortunately I dont see much room for accelration. If the workbook contains huge amounts of data, and formulas as well, it will take long to save or load. What you can do eventually is to not save it each time a user submits a form, just let the user decide when to save. Also, check if you have lot of formulas. If so, make the calculation ''manual' so it is not made until explicitly asked for.

Comment: You can however post another question providing more details about the structure of your workbook, its data, and the updated code, so that we may investigate it thoroughly and find the reason of slowness. The way I see it, the slowness is not inherent to the given code, but probably to something inside the WB.

Comment: I will certainly do that later on. I will have to wait 90 minutes before i can post another question. Thanks for your help though

Comment: By the way about your suggestion, do you think it will work even if the all the data will be dumped on a single worksheet. I'm afraid that if they manually save the file it might post conflict between each submission.

Comment: yes, saving the document or not, does not modify the way work is done (for a single user).